# Can't set custom page size in mac printer driver

Tags: printing, printer

I have a Konica Minolta bizhub printer and it has a bypass tray that can accommodate all sorts of custom paper sizes. But I can't seem to make the Mac Driver reflect that paper size, so when it gets sent to the printer, the printer interprets it with the default paper size (8.5"x11" in this case).

[Screenshot: custom page size defaulting to 8.5x11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDyML.png)

This is coming from an Adobe application (indd and acrobat both), but no matter what I do in the driver I cannot get it to send the job with the custom page size (16.3x3.7" in this case). All of the posts online for how to accomplish this show a windows driver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have done, but here is how to create a custom page size in OSX:

> Choose File > Print. If you see a Show Details button, click it to
> show all available options.
>
> Click the Paper Size pop-up menu, then choose Manage Custom Sizes.
>
> Click the Add button  to add a new paper size, then specify the paper
> size you want.